# Angular/Ionic: updating ng-change value in two controllers

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need a bit of a code review, i'm having trouble getting my ng-change function to trigger and update the value in both controllers, i've created a factory service and have injected it into both controllers but on the second AppCtrl console.log() value prints only once during initialization, and would like to have the ng-change value also update on the second controller and not only on the first.

This is what i have so far:

```
 <ion-radio ng-repeat="rate in rates"
                       ng-value="rate.id"
                       ng-change="rateTypeChanged(rate)"
                       ng-checked="rate.selected"
                       ng-model="currentRate.selectedRate">
                       {{ rate.title }}
            </ion-radio>
```

controller for sidebar:

```
.controller('SidebarCtrl', function($scope, typesOfRates) { 
$scope.rates = typesOfRates.rateType;

  $scope.currentRate = {
      selectedRate: 'hourly'
  };

  $scope.rateTypeChanged = function(rate) {
      console.log("Selected goalType, text:", rate.title, "value:", rate.id);
      typesOfRates.setRate(rate.id);
  }
```

In controller 2:

```
   .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, typesOfRates, $state, $rootScope) {
  console.log( typesOfRates.getRate() ); 
  //runs only once, but not again when ng-change event is triggered
```

my service:

```
  .factory('typesOfRates', function typesOfRates($rootScope) {

    var typesOfRates = {};
        typesOfRates.myRates = [];
        typesOfRates.rateType = [
            { title: "Hourly",  id: "hourly",  selected: true  },
            { title: "Daily",   id: "daily",   selected: false },
            { title: "Monthly", id: "monthly", selected: false }
        ];

        typesOfRates.currentRate = "hourly";

    var setRate = function(currentRate) {
        if (typesOfRates.myRates.length > 0) typesOfRates.myRates = [];
        typesOfRates.myRates.push(currentRate);
    }

    var getRate = function() {
        return typesOfRates.myRates;
    }

    return {
        rateType: typesOfRates.rateType,
        getRate:  getRate,
        setRate: setRate
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing to achieve the objective seems bit out of the box. The second controller will be initialized only once. If you want to access the undated value in the second controller you need to following one of the following approaches.

**1) Watch for changes in `typesOfRates.myRates` in the second controller.**

$watch is used to track changes for a model variable in the scope. The
$watch requires $scope, as we have 2 different controllers, the scopes will be different (I feel so unless you have bound the two controllers
in the same html). So it won't be the correct to use $watch in this
situation.

**2) Use a broad cast receiver concept**

> **Advantage :** It's preferred as there is no continuous watching required, and triggered only when the value changes

**Step 1) In the first controller, register a broadcast as:**

```
.controller('SidebarCtrl', function($scope, typesOfRates) { 
$scope.rates = typesOfRates.rateType;

  $scope.currentRate = {
      selectedRate: 'hourly'
  };

  $scope.rateTypeChanged = function(rate) {
      console.log("Selected goalType, text:", rate.title, "value:", rate.id);
      typesOfRates.setRate(rate.id);

      //$broadcast(name, args); here name you have to give in a file 
      //which is commonly accessible like constants.js, just create a 
      //file and include in you index.html, pass your rates as args
      $rootScope.$broadcast(constants_config.TYPE_RATES_CHANGED, rate.id);
  }
});
```

**Step 2) Create constants.js  file and include in your index.html as:**

```
<!-----Constants Classes---->
<script src="Constants.js"></script>
```

In constants.js add the following code:

```
var constants_config                      = {

    TYPE_RATES_CHANGED   :   "TYPE_RATES_CHANGED",
}
```

**Step 3) Register your listener in the second controller as**

```
 .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, typesOfRates, $state, $rootScope) {
    // @CallBack
    // Description : Callback function for user details fetched
    $scope.$on(constants_config.TYPE_RATES_CHANGED, function(args) {
        //Assign the value to a global variable or a scope variable so                 
        //that  you can access it throughout your controller
        $scope.Rates = typesOfRates.getRate();

        //Now the console will work
        console.log( typesOfRates.getRate() ); 
    });


 });
```

**Further Reference:**
 - Broadcasts : [$broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) 
 - Listeners  : [$on](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on) 
 - Watch      : [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Comment: Thanks for your response, your suggestion works.  You said the way i'm doing this was a bit different, can you suggest how this could be improved on?